# SharePoint 2013 Subsite inherits Parent Navigation - Managed Navigation

Tags: 2013, sub-site, managed-navigation

I am using Managed Navigation and have Variations defined, so the root site collection has two sub sites for each of the languages.. Each Language sub site has its own Terms Set and the navigation is using the Term Set for the Navigation respectively.

Now if I create a sub site under one of the Variations sub site (`http://servername/en-us/subsite`), than even if I select **No** in **Use the top link bar from the parent site?**, it still inherits the top navigation from Parent Site i.e. `http://servername/en-us`

What I want is that the Sub site should have its own Navigation Term Set and also when the Sub Site is created in the Target Variation sites.. They also should have their own Navigation Term Set.. There is no option for Creating Term Sets under Variations Term Set..

Can this be achieved through Configuration? Or can I do it Programmatically on Subsite creation? But how will I handle Target Sub site, since at the time of creation of sub site the Target Variation sub site doesn't exist..?

Answer (score 5):

It could be achieved by creating a separate Term Set for Variation Navigation and configuring Navigation settings for a Variation sub site

### How to configure Managed Navigation for a a Variation sub site

Assume we have Variation sub site named `News` for which we need to specify custom Global Navigation (Managed Navigation).

Steps:

- Go to Term Store Management Tool and create Term Set for a Variation
  sub site (in our case for a News site)

  [image]
- Go to Navigation settings for a News site and specify Navigation
  settings for a `Global Navigation` as demonstrated below

  [image]

### Results

Global Navigation for a Variation root site (default)
[image]

Global Navigation for a News variation sub site

[image]

Comment: The problem is its "Manual Process", What will happen to the sub-site that will be created in Target variation site i.e. https://server-name/de-de/news ?